# Network Sharing Problems Between 2 Laptops

Tags: networking, network-shares, user

Tried enabling network sharing on both laptops with LAN cable and wireless connection but only 1st laptop is able to access its own User under Network and User of 2nd laptop. The problem is that 2nd laptop cannot access nor his User under Network, nor User on 1st laptop and always shows me the following error (there's missing User of 1st laptop because it was not correct screenshot but assume there is):

[image]

But if 2nd laptop is [being invisible in HomeGroup](https://superuser.com/questions/696657/cannot-see-and-share-files-in-homegroup) then how can it be visible on 1st laptop as User under Network?

I have found article that instructs to use command **gpedit.msc** for accessing *Local Group Policy Editor* and enabling first option and disabling the rest 3 options:

[image]

I have not idea about this and whether I should mess with it further.

Comment: What's the OS of the laptop that's invisible, Home Premium?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise